# No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"categories"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

I am stuck on storing all the categories to an instance in the database.

Here is the instructions: 
In categories_controller.rb, under def index, write the body of the index method for categories. 
Remember to follow the example closely and close with end. Hit Run.

Here is my code:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end

  private 
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, :thumburl)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Marek Lipka's answer is correct. Also, make sure you change method name `delete` to `destroy` if you're going to rely on just `resources :categories` to create CRUD methods for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :categories
```

I'd also suggest to learn some Rails basics.

Comment: yes but this tutorial is in codecademy so they don't show me the config/routes.rb file so I can't add resources